# QGIS python support disabled

Tags: qgis, python

I'm having a problem with the python support of my QGIS version. When I start QGIS, I get the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "", line 1, in
ImportError: Module use of python34.dll conflicts with this version of Python.

Then the python version and the QGIS version are displayed, followed by a bulk of path descriptions.

Since the python version displayed in the error message (2.7.5) doesn't match the python version I've installed (3.4), I tried to remove the python34.dll in the system32 folder, but that leads to a similar error, something like:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "", line 1, in
ImportError: Couldn't find module

Do you have any ideas how to fix that? I don't want to downgrade my python version. Is there a way to tell QGIS to use a a newer version of python? I'm using windows 7, 64bit.

Comment: It is a problem of paths, QGIS uses Python 2.7.x (independent, not in the registry) and not Python 3.x.

Comment: Okay, any ideas how to change the path so that QGIS finds the right version?

Comment: eliminate all the Python 3.x references in the registry and in the windows paths

Comment: You may not need to touch the registry yourself. I was simply able to ininstall python 3.x